# Install Apple Symbol font on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, font

I use MacBook Pro Retina ME864 with Mac OSX 10.9.4 ,
Recently I download a Word file from internet which use Apple Symbol font and because I don't have this font on my system the characters shows wrong.

How can I install Apple Symbol font ?

Comment: If you mean the Apple Symbols font, it should already be in `/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Symbols.ttf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the font from below, then drag and drop that file into Font Book.app

- [https://gitorious.org/deblock/iphone/raw/ce72bc0d9bc69ffcaef4320450aeb5a38003d663:Resources/Fonts/Apple%20Symbols.ttf](https://gitorious.org/deblock/iphone/raw/ce72bc0d9bc69ffcaef4320450aeb5a38003d663%3aResources/Fonts/Apple%20Symbols.ttf)